# Stable conjugacy class in $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(k)$ for a non-algebraically closed field $k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B\in \mathrm{SL}_{2}(k)$ be matrices. At least for $k = \mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, there exists two matrices such that they are conjugate by matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\overline{k})$ or in $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(k)$, but not in $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(k)$. 
For example, if 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
then they are not conjugate by element in $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$ if $a, b\neq 0$ and $a/b$ is not square. (This can be checked by hand). 
I want to know this is true for any non-algebraically closed field. Especially,

- Is there any field $k$ which is not algebraically closed but $\sqrt{a} \in k$ for any $a\in k$? I seems that this is possible if we keep adding square roots of elements.
- If such $k$ exists, is it still true that we can find two matrices that satisfy the same properties?

Comment: Let $p \ne 2, k = \bigcup_n \Bbb{F}_{\displaystyle p^{ 2^n}}$ what is the Jordan normal form of $A \in GL_2(k)$ when is it conjugate to $B$ over $GL_2(\overline{\Bbb{F}_p})$ ?

Comment: @reuns Thank you! So all the stable conjugate matrices are actually conjugate for such field. This seems also true for $\mathrm{SL}_{m}(k)$ with $k = \mathbb{F}_{p^{m^{\infty}}}$, right?

Comment: You meant $k= \mathbb{F}_{\displaystyle p^{m!^{\infty}}}$. Also do you see when a Jordan normal form $P J P^{-1} \in GL_n(K)$ for $P,J \in GL_n(\overline{K})$ ?